# Accessing parameter from where clause function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I understand that with "normal" functions, I can access parameters on the top-level from within a function defined in a `where` clause. However, when I try the same thing with monadic functions, I get a compile-time error.

This works:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.ST (ST, runST)
import Data.Array.ST    (STUArray, newArray, readArray)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ runST $ do
              arr <- newArray (0, 9) 0
              checkArr arr
  return ()

checkArr :: STUArray s Int Int -> ST s Bool
checkArr arr = do
  val <- readArr arr
  return $ val == 0
  where
    readArr :: STUArray s Int Int -> ST s Int
    readArr arr = readArray arr 0
```

But this does not:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.ST (ST, runST)
import Data.Array.ST    (STUArray, newArray, readArray)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ runST $ do
              arr <- newArray (0, 9) 0
              checkArr arr
  return ()

checkArr :: STUArray s Int Int -> ST s Bool
checkArr arr = do
  val <- readArr
  return $ val == 0
  where
    readArr :: ST s Int
    readArr = readArray arr 0
```

It results in the following error:

```
No instance for (Data.Array.Base.MArray (STUArray s) Int (ST s1)) arising from a use of ‘readArray’
```

Why can't I access the `arr` parameter of `checkArr` in `readArr`?

Comment: Well do you understand what a monad is? It is not impossible to perform the function, but you will not obtain the "value", but the `Monad value`.

Comment: That is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Well to be honest, I think it is better to first have some understanding about monads, before mixing it with `where` clauses, etc. Monads like the state monad, actually are used partly to exactly prevent getting the state it wraps in a where clause, since that state might change, and by using a `where` clause, it would create unpredictable behaviour when exactly you obtain the state/value it stores.

Comment: In fact, you can access the value, and the error message is telling you something slightly different. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that the error message says something about lacking an instance declaration rather than unknown variable name. Furthemore, as a first hint, note that the error message contains two different `ST` tags: `s` arising from `STUArray` (which is related to the `arr` parameter of your function), and another `s1` in `ST s1`. Where does that `s1` come from? Indeed, there is no mention of it in your program!

As a second hint, try removing the signature declaration for `readArr`, so that the `where` clause looks like just

```
  where
    readArr = readArray arr 0
```

Suddenly that typechecks and works just fine. What's going on?

The answer is that when you wrote `readArr :: ST s Int`, you meant the `s` from the `checkArr` signature, but the scoping rules are such that this actually introduces a new type variable, which the typechecker renames for you into `s1`, and `s` doesn't necessarily match with `s1`, hence the type error. If you omit this signature, then the typechecker is able to derive the correct type itself.

If you really want to write the type in a `where`-binding like this, there's an extension for that! [`ScopedTypeVariables`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables) allows you to refer to a free variable (which the `s` from `checkArr` signature is) from within the function. So, add a `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` and let the typechecker know you want it scoped by writing an explicit `forall` in the top-level signature: `checkArr :: forall s. STUArray s Int Int -> ST s Bool`. After that, your code will typecheck.

Comment: I thought that it had something to do with `s` and `s1`, but I could not figure out how to fix it. This example is actually part of a larger program that I am writing to solve Sudoku puzzles, as an exercise to learn/improve my Haskell. In my larger code, I got an error about ambiguous declarations when I left out the type on the `readArray`, but I did not know or understand about `ScopedTypeVariables`. Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Comment: @Ralph FWIW you probably don't need to mess around with `ST` just to write a su doku solver. In fact I would expect it to be significantly easier to write it in a pure style, given that su doku involves backtracking. (`ST` is a monad for writing high performance imperative code which directly accesses mutable memory locations.)